# Iterator set in insert function

Tags: c++, insert, iterator

I am implementing an iterator for Graph class

```
class iterator_node {
    private:
        Graph* gr_;
        Node* curNode_;
    public:
        iterator_node() : gr_(NULL),curNode_(NULL) {}
        iterator_node(Graph& ddg) : gr_(&ddg),curNode_(NULL) {}
        ~iterator_node() {}
}
```

As well I have a `Graph` class for which I should implement `insert` function

```
class Graph {
private:
//....
map<NodeID,Node*> nodes_;
public:
pair<iterator_node,bool> insert(const NodeID nodeId,const NodeLabel nodeLabel);
}
pair<iterator_node,bool> Graph::insert(const NodeID nodeId,const NodeLabel nodeLabel)
{
    DDG::iterator_node itNode(*this);
    pair<Graph::iterator_node,bool> res(itNode,false);
    Node* node = new Node(nodeId,false,nodeLabel);
    pair<map<NodeID,Node*>::iterator,bool> nodeInsRet  = nodes_.insert(pair<NodeID,Node*> (nodeId,node));
    if (nodeInsRet.second == false) {
        std::cout << "Node with nodeID=" << nodeId << " already exists \n";
        delete node;
    }
    else {
        res.second = true;
       //!!Question!!!!
       //should update curNode_; in res`s iterator (res.first)
       //what is a relevan correct way to do it?
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Hm, would you mind making your question a bit more clear?

Answer (score 2):

Your iterator can't iterate unless it can move from one element to the next. With your current code incrementing the `iterator_node` you'd have to search the entire `Graph` for the current `Node` and then find the next one ... which would be incredibly slow.

Either you need to link each `Node` to its neighbours, or your `iterator_node` should store a `map<NodeID,Node*>::iterator` instead of a `Node*`